# Add spreading Shadow to the bottom of button Android

Tags: android, xml, button

I searched about the shadow button (shown below) but haven't found the desired result. I want same as shown in the image below.

[image]

I tried this also [How to provide shadow to Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button).

I also tried elevation and translation Z (z) android method for shadow but nothing helped. Please guide me through this.
Thank you.

Comment: provide your outcome using elevation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: android:translationZ="@null"
 android:elevation="24dp"

Comment: @ThanhTranIT Already try this link but not same as my given image.

Comment: one quick solution ,use 9.patch images for this, tell designer to create that type of image with bottom shadow.

Comment: @Radhey shadow area show as bad patches. How i resolve it.

Comment: refer sites from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426518/bad-patches-in-9-patch-file this to create .9patch

Comment: To add Radhey's suggestion. you can use this site to build 9 patch shadows http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @user7856586 Yes I did with android elevation shadow line android:elevation ="24dp" in xml.

Comment: Thanks, here you can find my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52736354/7856586)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own xml file in `drawable` folder and set in your button background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--the shadow comes from here-->
    <item
        android:bottom="-6dp"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
        android:left="-6dp"
        android:right="-6dp"
        android:top="-6dp">

    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="-6dp"
        android:left="-6dp"
        android:right="-6dp"
        android:top="-6dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: its show dialog shadow but I use own pink color shadow with rounded corner. How it implement?

Comment: Change your solid color whatever you want.

Comment: I am not say about base color. I say about background shadow of dialog is black but i want pink. and dialog shadow not spread like my given image.

Comment: How to change color of shadow?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Quick Shadow Color Glow]

Set your button's attributes to

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
android:backgroundTint="@color/cool"
```

The tint is for api 21+ but you can walk around this programmically using

```
button.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(parseColor(tintColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/your_btncolor" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="-15dp"
        android:left="-5dp"
        android:right="-5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/your_btn_shadowcolor" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```