# Adding a colored shadow to a Button

Tags: android, shadow

I need to add a shadow to a Button with these attributes "from zeplin":

[image]

and this is the design

[image]

I tried this code

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/auth_button_shape"
        android:shadowColor="#41ff4800"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="8"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

auth_button_shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#ff7c44" />
<corners android:radius="100dp" />
</shape>
```

But not worked and the other attributes "Blur" and "Spread" How I can set them for the button.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, I used drawables for buttons like this, and add elevations in other cases.

Comment: Did you get colored shadow?

Comment: No, As I said in the above comment I used drawables and grey shadows

Comment: Hi @M.SH could you post your final code? I encounter the same need, and the elevation doesn't seem to work to add a shadow...

Comment: Really sorry, But I can't figure it out So, I used some drawables to solve this case  and use default elevation in other cases.

Comment: I figured it out. Take a look here, think that's what you were searching for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583069/how-to-put-shadow-with-gradient

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Taras I have solution. You can use this [library](https://github.com/Devlight/ShadowLayout) for creating colored shadow to button. Just place your view element inside shadow layout. Of course basic layout is ConstraintLayout.
Some pieces of code for example

```
 <com.gigamole.library.ShadowLayout
    android:id="@+id/shadowLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:sl_shadow_angle="90"
    app:sl_shadow_color="@color/light_orange_color"
    app:sl_shadow_distance="2dp"
    app:sl_shadow_radius="7dp"
    app:sl_shadowed="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivYourImageName"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</com.gigamole.library.ShadowLayout>
```

Button shape :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <gradient android:angle="180" android:endColor="#ffc349" android:startColor="#ff8006" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you need to add this line of code  inside button tag

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

because button override any evelation value you set by passing null to android:stateListAnimator it will remove stateList attrs

for color you can add this line to show colored shadow

```
android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#303030"
```

check answer

[Android elevation not showing shadow on Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278179/android-elevation-not-showing-shadow-on-button)

Answer (score 1):

**`bg_test.xml` :**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--the shadow comes from here-->
    <item
        android:bottom="-6dp"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
        android:left="-6dp"
        android:right="-6dp"
        android:top="-6dp">

    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="-6dp"
        android:left="-6dp"
        android:right="-6dp"
        android:top="-6dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                android:color="@color/yellow" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

**`Activity.xml` code:**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/sign_In"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_80sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_test" />
```

Design Button :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `AppCompatButton` instead of `Button`,use `elevation` and use `android:backgroundTint` for button colour.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sign_in"
        android:backgroundTint="#ccd3e0ea"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>
```

output is,

[image]